# Create poetry-like lines indents in html using blockquotes, pre, or dd tags?

Tags: html, pre, dd

I want to write a few lines of text in indentations (in HTML ONLY), like in this example: [HERE](http://i1368.photobucket.com/albums/ag166/clover69m/here_zps2b67d795.png)

And below is what I tried:

```
<p><code>"Knowing is not enough. We</code></p>
<p><blockquote><code>must apply. Willing is not</code></blockquote></p>
<p><blockquote><pre><code>enough. We must do."</code></pre></blockquote></p>
```

And it doesn't work. The next 2 lines doesn't indent similarly to the example.

Could anyone kindly point out my errors here?

Also, I'd like to know how to make the spaces between those 3 lines not so widely gapped? Or does it depend on the type of text used? (Like, if you see here, I used  tags for the texts.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The space comes from you using [paragraphs](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), for a quick fix try using `div`instead of `p`.

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for: indenting to the left, aligning to the right, or something else.

Comment: You can use the `pre` tag and manually insert the amount of space.

Comment: @ANeves Indenting to the right. I have updated the picture view of the original small window example. And no, the jsfiddle did not represent the desired alignment :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation really belongs with the styling, as it's presentation and not semantic meaning that HTML should represent.

However to do this with html only, just consider using breaks and nbsp tags

```
<p>
"Knowing is not enough, we<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;must apply. Willing is not<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;enough, we must do."</p>
```

Just increase the number of nbsp tags to adjust the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You could ditch the pre and other block quots and use styles to define your indentations, then mark up your line indentation levels.  For example:

```
<div>"Knowing is not enough, we</div>
<div style="text-indent:30px;">must apply. Willing is not</div>
<div style="text-indent:70px;">enough, we must do."</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a monospace-font presentation as in the image linked to in the question, the simplest method is to use just the `pre` element:

```
<pre>
“Knowing is not enough. We 
              must apply. Willing is not
                    enough. We must do.”
</pre>
```

Result:

```
“Knowing is not enough. We 
              must apply. Willing is not
                    enough. We must do.”
```

However, generally it’s more flexible to wrap each line in a `div` element and use CSS to set indentation for them with `margin-left`. This lets you use variable-width fonts. You then need to choose suitable units, like `em` or (with more limited browser support) `ch` for the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could align the first row left, and the other two right.

To make the poem not take the whole width of the page, you can add width limitations on the element.
(Please clarify these things in the question's text.)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hhh87/4/

```
<div style="text-align: right; min-width:300px; max-width: 40%;">
    <div style="text-align: left;">"Knowing is not enough, we</div>
    <div>must apply. Willing is not</div>
    <div>enough, we must do."</div>
</div>
```

---

### CSS Alternative

Of course, Ideally you would use a CSS file and not set the styles inline.
Then you could also style it more generically:

HTML:

```
<div class="poem">
    <div>"Knowing is not enough, we</div>
    <div>must apply. Willing is not</div>
    <div>enough, we must do."</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.poem > * {
    text-align: right;
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 40%;
}
.poem > *:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will do the trick.  That will align to the right of the page, which will mean it will indent too far if the page is wide.  Furthermore, depending on the length of the third line, the indentation may be way off.  If the user is looking for increasing indentations, regardless of screen width or line length, then I think specifying indentation is the way to go.

Comment: is there really no other way to do this in HTML ONLY without using css, aside from using spaces?

Comment: @R.Barzell but to me the example does not seem indented, it seems aligned, because the second and third rows align perfectly on the right... it cannot be a coincidence.

Comment: @Ururu you have to use **either** whitespace, or CSS align/indent/something.

Comment: @ANeves that's odd, because they don't look aligned to me.  They're close, but the last line is a bit further to the left than the line above it, but that could be an illusion thanks to the font and the quote...  It also doesn't help that the poetry is in a small window to begin with.

Comment: @R.Barzell here is the example with borders around the elements, that you can see better the alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/hhh87/2/

Comment: @ANeves Did the original poster say anything about whether that fiddle represented the desired alignment?

Comment: @R.Barzell Not yet, no. I asked him to clarify, in a comment to the question.

Comment: @ANeves I have updated the example view of the small window :)